# d3 equivalent of jquery on(events, selector) to attach events to DOM elements not created yet

Tags: d3.js, events

I am used to jquery, but am trying to get to grips with using d3.

In jquery, you could do

```
$('body').on('click', 'div.hint', myEventFunction);
```

If you subsequently create a `<div class="hint">` in code, `myEventFunction` is called whenever you click it, even though it didn't exist when `on` was called.

Is there a d3 equivalent to this, or do I manually have to keep attaching myEventFunction to every new `div.hint` I create?

Comment: Your interpretation is a bit off: the function does **not** append listeners to any elements created after that call. The listener is only attached to the `body` element itself and can receive events via event bubbling. The argument `'div.hint'` is merely a filter of which target elements will be handled by the listener.  A D3 equivalent would roughly look like `d3.select("body").on("click", event => { if (d3.select(event.target).filter("div.hint").empty()) return; myEventFunction(); } );`.

Comment: I didn't actually say it appended listeners, all I said was that when you click on the thing, the function gets called. But I know understand more fully how it works, so thankyou.